# how to delete a div which has been created using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my following code I have created a div using java script.when i click the button the *div* is displayed repeatedly.What should I do to display once and get cleared.

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>Div tag using Javascript
</title>
<!--<link href="divtag1.js" type="text/javascript">-->
<style>
body{
    background:#00ffff;
}
.myclass{
    background:#30a0d3;
    color:#123456;
    position:relative;
    left:300px;
    right:300px;
    top:150px;
    height:100px;
    width:700px;
    border:2px solid #000000;
    border radius:5px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:50px;
}

</style>

<script>
function myfunction(){
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "my <b>new</b> skill - <large>DOM maniuplation!</large>";
// set style
div.style.color = 'red';
// better to use CSS though - just set class
div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass'); // and make sure myclass has some styles in css
document.body.appendChild(div);
var oldChild=element.removeChild(child)
element.removeChild(child);
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me!!" onclick="return myfunction();"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: set id for that element then delete it by id

Answer (score 1):

**Give your created `div` a unique `id`.** That way, you can parse the DOM *with* that `id`, and correctly delete it.

Example:

```
var mydiv = document.createElement("div");
mydiv.setAttribute("id", "deleteme");//set the ID to "deleteme"
```

Now you can reference the created DIV, and do what you will with it (including deleting it).

Answer (score 0):

The code below is the issue.  child is not defined

```
var oldChild=element.removeChild(child)
element.removeChild(child);
```

You need to have a way to refer to your elements that you insert.  If you are just using standard Javascript, aka no jQuery, then assigning ids is the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

give some id to div created by you using javascript and delete it using

```
$('#yourdivid').html(''); // this will clear contents of your division
```

Comment: This will return html of the id ,`$('#yourdivid').html('')` is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Div tag using Javascript
</title>
<!--<link href="divtag1.js" type="text/javascript">-->
<style>
body{
    background:#00ffff;
}
.myclass{
    background:#30a0d3;
    color:#123456;
    position:relative;
    left:300px;
    right:300px;
    top:150px;
    height:100px;
    width:700px;
    border:2px solid #000000;
    border radius:5px;
    padding:20px;
    margin:50px;
}

</style>

<script>
var once= false;
function myfunction(){
    if(once==true){
        return;
    }
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "my <b>new</b> skill - <large>DOM maniuplation!</large>";
// set style
div.style.color = 'red';
// better to use CSS though - just set class
div.setAttribute('class', 'myclass'); // and make sure myclass has some styles in css
document.body.appendChild(div);
once= true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me!!" onclick="return myfunction();"></div>
</body>
</html>
```